# Convegence of regularized sequence in $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

Let $(\rho_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a standard regularizing sequence on $\mathbb R$. Let $P$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb R$ such that the sequence $(P*\rho_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is bounded in $L^2$. Then, does the probability measure $P$ admit a density in $ L^2$? i.e., is there a $p \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ satisfying
\begin{align}
P(dx) = p (x) dx?
\end{align}
My understanding is that, due to the boundedness in $L^2$, the sequence $(P*\rho_n)_{n \geq 0}$ contains a subsequence, which converges weakly to a limit in $L^2$. But, how do we know that the density $p$ is the limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand, we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} P \ast \rho_n \to P$ in the sense of distributions (Laurent Schwartz, not probability distributions). On the other hand, by the assumed boundedness in $L^2$, we have a subsequence such that $P\ast \rho_{n_k}$ converges weakly to $p$ in $L^2$. Weak convergence in $L^2$ implies convergence in the sense of distributions, and $\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ is Hausdorff, so limits are unique. Hence we have "$p = P$" (more precisely $P$ is the measure with density $p$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure). Since $p$ is therefore the only possible weak limit of a subsequence, in fact the entire sequence $P\ast \rho_n$ converges weakly to $p$.

Comment: That is really a nice answer, thank you so much. Now I understand the idea, but I am still a little bit confused about some details. Actually, I am wondering if you could recommend me some notes or books on Schwartz distribution? Since regarding this topic, I also have several other questions. For example, I've read in a paper the statement 'If a positive measure can be represented as the difference of two convex functions, then it admits a continuous density w.r.t the Lebesgue measure', but never understood why... I appreciate.

Comment: Most (good) books on functional analysis treat distributions to some extent. For a start, I think the chapter(s) in Rudin dealing with distributions isn't bad. Concerning the difference of convex functions, the point is that convex functions are nice (absolutely continuous; so they are the integral of their derivative), and hence so is their difference. That's more plain analysis than functional analysis, a book on measure theory should treat that, also analysis books, e.g. Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis.

Comment: @DanielFischer Perhaps I'm missing something simple, but doesn't $P \ast p_n \to P^{-}$ in the sense of distributions; here $P^{-}(E) = P(-E)$ with $-E = \{-x : x \in E\}$. Your argument then still holds with the slight alteration that $P^{-}(dx) = p(x)dx \implies P(dx) = p(-x) \, dx$.

Comment: @Tom Not with the definition of convolution I am familiar with. You have $(P\ast\rho_n)[\varphi] = P[\rho_n\ast\varphi]$, and $$(\rho_n\ast\varphi)(x) = \int \varphi(x-y)\rho_n(y)\,dy \to \varphi(x).$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, ok. My intuition was that $$(P\ast \rho_n)[\varphi] = \int \varphi(x) \Big( \int \rho_n(x-y)P(dy) \Big) dx$$ from which it is clear why I was "so negative."

Comment: @Tom Oops, it was $P[\check{\rho}_n\ast \varphi]$, sorry. But nevertheless, if $\rho_n \to \delta$, so does $\check{\rho}_n$ (where $\check{g}(x) = g(-x)$).